# EC2/ELB Health Check Fails with Nginx/Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have got an Ec2/RHEL7 behind an ELB. EC2 has Nginx listening on port 80 and Tomcat on 8080. ELB Healthcheck is as follows

```
Ping Target 
HTTP:80/index.html
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 10
Healthy threshold   3
```

ELB health check keeps failing and ec2 goes out-of-service

I have updated ngix conf (under both site-available and sites-enabled) 
both Nginx and tomcat services are up and running

I am also able to curl the following (PASS with localhost and hostname, but fails with IP address)

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-190-180-30 ~]$ curl -I  localhost:80/index.html
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2017 06:05:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://localhost/index.html
Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"

curl -I  10.160.xx.xx:80/index.html
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: squid/3.5.20
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2017 06:07:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3659
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 110
X-Cache: MISS from izss-proxy-a2
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from izss-proxy-a2:3128
Via: 1.1 izss-proxy-a2 (squid/3.5.20)
Connection: keep-alive
```

ELB health check is failing. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Post your nginx config

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like nginx is listening on localhost only, to check this you can do

```
$ ss -l -t | grep http
```

This will list all TCP ports named something with http that any process is listening on.

It should show something like this:

```
LISTEN     0      128        *:http-alt                 *:*                    
LISTEN     0      128        *:http                     *:*
```

If there isn't a `*` in front of `:http` but `127.0.0.1` instead this is your issue and you should check your nginx config after a `listen` option and change it to `*:80`, if you can't find it add it.

Comment: the output looks okay, but still health check fails   ss -l -t | grep http
LISTEN     0      128        *:http                     *:*
LISTEN     0      128        *:https                    *:*

Answer (score 0):

Check you ec2 security group and ensure port 80 is accessible to the ELB.

Best practise would be to take the ELB security group and create an inbound rule on ec2 security group to allow the ELB security group access to port 80 on the ec2.